# How incapsulate dbquery into automapping profile

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I try to pass from EF entity to dto in business layer.

So I setup Automapper and everything goes well.

Here is my profile class:

```
    public DocumentProfile()
        {
             CreateMap<Data.Models.Docflow.Package, PackageDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ReceiverName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Receiver.FullName))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.SenderName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Sender.FullName))

                ;
        }
```

But I make mapping from Package to PackageDto in different places of my code. And I have different specific queries in different cases. So I need to remember to include navigation properties Receiver and Sender in all queries.

**So how can I incapsulate single query for Package entity with all necessary properties for certain projection?**

I saw examples with value resolvers and type converters but it seems not suitable.

Comment: Look at *flattening* with AutoMapper.

Comment: If you use ProjectTo instead of Map, you don't need the Includes. By default ProjectTo will fetch everything in the dto.

Comment: @gert-arnold, what do you mean? but anyway I already use flattening mapping complex entity to simple dto class.

Comment: @lucian-bargaoanu, as I understand it's possible to use ProjectTo with IQueriable but I work with "in memory" entity objects or their IEnumerable collections

Comment: OK, so how could AM possibly help with Include if you're mapping in memory :) You need to reuse your queries the old fashioned way, with functions.

Comment: But are the any way to incapsulate this query into ITypeConverter or smth else? I see one. As I understand I could use cfg.CreateMap<Package, PackageDto>().ConvertUsing<TypeTypeConverter>(). I could perform query in this converter but I must realize all mappings manually in this case loosing automatic naming projections. But I'm not sure it's right way..

Comment: A C# function is the way to go here. An extension method for IQueryable<Package> that applies the includes for example.

Answer (score 0):

@lucian-bargaoanu, thanks for your comments!

Finally I came in to 2 suitable solutions.

Shared part is:

I prepare function like **PackageDto Get(Guid packageId)** in Repository and I incapulate dbquery with mapping to dto in repository and in BL I work only with dto.

But the difference is:

1. dbquery returns needed entity type in memory that is mapped then by Mapper.Map<>
2. dbquery returns IQueryable, that then extended by ProjectTo

Anyway It's necessary set profile with mapping rules, but second way is clearly as it performs includes that you need automatically.